# Como utilizar o maxResults e startAt corretamente em requisição ao jira

Tags: requisição

Tenho a seguinte requisição ao jira:

```
https://jira.spring.io/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=SPR+and+issuetype=Bug
```

Mas ela sempre retorna apenas as 50 mais recentes, como posso mudar para receber mais de 50 e também definir um valor inicial ?

Sei que e utilizado **maxResults** e **startAt** mas não consegui colocar eles na requisição sem dar erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

```
https://jira.spring.io/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=SPR+and+issuetype=Bug&maxResults=-1&startAt=0
```